# Google Cloud Platform: resources used during free trial can exceed 300$?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I hope this question fits here, since this forum is indicated on GoogleCloud as a suggested source of information.

I just used all my 300$ in my free trial and, if I see the billing account of the expenses, they sum exactly to that amount.

Nevertheless, the last expense was an online usage of a service, which is paid "per request". It is quite strange that the cost of the last service summed up exactly to 300$. Also, if I see the reports, I should have spent much more according to the per-item pricing (according to my calculations, around 450$).

I imagine that the cost is evaluated periodically, the account terminated when the expenses exceed 300$, and the last services scaled so that the billing corresponds to 300$. Is this correct ? I could not find confirmation anywhere...

If this is correct, I would like also to understand if I decide to upgrade from my free trial, will I be all of a sudden billed the remaining 150$ ?

I apologize if this question does not fit this forum. In case please suggest in the comments a better place to ask and I can also consider cancelling my question, if it does not fit.

Answer (score 2):

### Exceeding Free Tier usage limits

Any usage above Free Tier usage limits is automatically billed at standard rates.

You can help monitor and control costs by setting up budgets and alerts through the Google Cloud Console.

**update**

**The Free Trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days, whichever happens first.** At that time, the following conditions apply:

To continue using Google Cloud, you must upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account. **All resources you created during the trial are stopped.**

For more information check the information on [**Google Cloud Free Program**](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#free-trial)

### 90-day, $300 Free Trial

The Free Trial provides you with free Cloud Billing credits to pay for resources used while you learn about Google Cloud.

During your Free Trial period, when you use resources covered by the Free Tier, the Free Tier usage is not charged against your Free Trial credits.

### End of the Free Trial

The Free Trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days, whichever happens first. At that time, the following conditions apply:

To continue using Google Cloud, you must upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account.
All resources you created during the trial are stopped.
Any data you stored in Compute Engine is marked for deletion and might be lost. Learn more about data deletion on Google Cloud.
Your Cloud Billing account enters a 30-day grace period, during which you can recover resources and data you stored in any Google Cloud services during the trial period.
You might receive a message stating that your Cloud Billing account has been canceled, which indicates that your account has been suspended to prevent charges.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand the answer to my question. I received a message that I ended my free trial because I used all 300$. Is it possible in such a situation to have used more than 300$ (say 450$), so that as soon as I activate my account, I will be billed the remaining 150$ ?

Comment: In other words,  is it possible to be on the "Exceeding Free Tier usage limits" side, even if I am in my free trial and I did not yet upgrade to a paying program ? Shouldn't Google Cloud stop me in this case from using resources more than 300$ ?

Comment: @Thomas - your question does not have details on what you have consumed, how you calculate an additional $150. We can only speculate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can add more details. Essentially I got N calls to a service, and if I multiply the number of calls times the price I arrive at 450. But in the report this number looks to be cut out so that the total arrives to 300. The service is a machine learning model from vertex AI and I read the price per call from the same "billing" page in my Google cloud console.

Comment: Apparently anyway the overall report is reassuring, in the sense that it says "Cost: 300",  "Promotion: -300" ; "Subtotal: 0", even if, as I said, I have evaluated a cost higher than "300". But I just wanted to be sure that when I upgrade, I do not start paying for resources used during the period in which I should not have been billed, up to my understanding.

Comment: Is there something that I can check to be sure that this does not happen?

Comment: Hey. 

**The Free Trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days, whichever happens first.** At that time, the following conditions apply:

To continue using Google Cloud, you must upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account. **All resources you created during the trial are stopped.**

Comment: Thanks. So you want to say that it is impossible to use more than 300$ without upgrading and therefore I cannot be billed for past usage if I start my upgrade now ? Is this what you want to say?

Comment: Hi @Thomas Although I do not have answers to your question, I'd like to tell you that I understand your concern & situation because I'm in that situation as well. I'm afraid that Alejandro didn't understand our situation